# I need to add lock to my dictionary add, How do I add lock to this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I have this code in my c# web application, which is producing this error "C# System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert - An item with the same key has already been added", so I researched a bit and found the issue is because I need lock on the following code.

```
if (keyVals == null)
{
    keyVals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}

if (activity != null)
{
        keyVals.Add(string.Format("{0}S1", prefix), test.GetType().FullName);
        keyVals.Add(string.Format("{0}S2", prefix), test.acode);
        keyVals.Add(string.Format("{0}S3", prefix), test.id.ToString());
        keyVals.Add(string.Format("{0}S4", prefix), test.unme);
}
else
{
    keyVals.Add("testtype", "N/A");
}
```

So in the above code, can I just use lock like this

```
using (new Lock(myLockObject))
{
 if (keyVals == null)
    {
        keyVals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    
    if (activity != null)
    {
        keyVals.Add(string.Format("{0}S1", prefix), test.GetType().FullName);
        keyVals.Add(string.Format("{0}S2", prefix), test.acode);
        keyVals.Add(string.Format("{0}S3", prefix), test.id.ToString());
        keyVals.Add(string.Format("{0}S4", prefix), test.unme);
    }
    else
    {
        keyVals.Add("testtype", "N/A");
    }
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Consider using a [ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) which: *"Represents a thread-safe collection of key/value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently."*

Comment: You can try and test if key,value pair already exists in your dictionary before doing the add, like this: if (dict.ContainsKey(key)) { /*do your add*/ }

Comment: Are you just looking for [the `lock` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock)?

Comment: @olivier: I can't use concurrentDictionary at the moment, because the method has various references and I can't chnage them now

Comment: @David: I am wondering if I need to add lock for each add statement

Comment: @Geoffrey: I'll try this

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` implements `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`. So, if you could change these references to be the interface instead ...

Comment: How on earth did you research this? I don't even know that .Net has a Lock class.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Most of the `IDictionary<,>` members aren't atomic across calls, though, so it's doubtful that accessing `ConcurrentDictionary<,>` via the interface is going to help.

Comment: Locks are only needed when you have two different processes accessing the data.  Having a duplicate key may not require a lock.  You should always check to make sure a key doesn't exist before adding new data.

Comment: If you decide to keep using the non-thread-safe `Dictionary<K,V>` and protect it with the `lock` statement, be sure that you use the `lock` **everywhere** you interact with the dictionary, including subordinate objects like the `Keys` collection and the enumerator, using always the same locker object. No exceptions allowed to this rule. A single unprotected access to the dictionary renders your program incorrect and its behavior undefined.

Comment: @Techno: Did that work?